# How to check if a "lateinit" variable has been initialized?

Tags: kotlin

I wonder if there is a way to check if a `lateinit` variable has been initialized. For example:

```
class Foo() {

    private lateinit var myFile: File

    fun bar(path: String?) {
        path?.let { myFile = File(it) }
    }

    fun bar2() {
        myFile.whateverMethod()
        // May crash since I don't know whether myFile has been initialized
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe what you need is to make the property nullable (change type to `File?`) and just check if it is null instead?

Comment: Well, I actually tried that and it will do the trick, however I will have to edit the `allSeries` var to `seriesDir?.listFiles()?.map { it.name }?.toTypedArray()`, which is not very "pretty"

Comment: You can do a plain old null check and smart cast will make it prettier.
`if (seriesDir != null) {`
`allSeries = seriesDir.listFiles().map { it.name }.toTypedArray()`
`}`

Comment: Please consider accepting more up to date [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584412/7598113)

Answer (score 1689, accepted):

There is a `lateinit` improvement in Kotlin 1.2 that allows you to check the initialization state of `lateinit` variable directly:

```
lateinit var file: File    

if (this::file.isInitialized) { ... }
```

See the annoucement on [JetBrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/09/kotlin-1-2-beta-is-out/) or the [KEEP proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/pull/73).

**UPDATE:** Kotlin 1.2 has been released. You can find `lateinit` enhancements here:

- [Checking whether a lateinit var is initialized](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized)
- [Lateinit top-level properties and local variables](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#lateinit-top-level-properties-and-local-variables)

Comment: @fer.marino: Well, Kotlin 1.2 actually allows you to use `lateinit` also for local variables, see http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#lateinit-top-level-properties-and-local-variables

Comment: This ain't working for me. I get "lateinit property has not been initialized" even after using it.

Comment: this::lateinitVar.isInitialized

Comment: what is meaning of `::` before `file`?

Comment: @MalwinderSingh it creates a member reference or a class reference.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh it creates a member reference like @notGeek mentioned. Since here we are referring to the reference within this class, the ```this``` keyword is not necessary. The verbose syntax is ```if (this::file.isInitialized) { ... }```

Comment: You should add a disclaimer warning that using this method is by no means the intended way to use the lateinit modifier in a pro environment.

Comment: Oh yeah, should have guessed that we need two colons in a row.  Monkeys typing could have figured that out in a few hundred years.  And it's soooo more intuitive and easier to type than `if (file == null)`.  I'm glad kotlin saves us so much typing and is so easy to understand!

Comment: How do we check this for local `lateinit`, where `this` is something different?

Comment: It seems that this can be done from inside the class, but I can't find any source.

Comment: Abhijit Sarkar "this" in "this::file path.isInitialized() references a fragment or activity... So if let's say you need to call it inside of a coroutine , you can make a variable to reference your fragment like - val fragment = MyFragment() and then do "fragment::filePath.isInitialized() ".... Or if "this" references a context (which it usually does), you can use "requireContext() " instead of "this".

Comment: using `isInitialized` is a code smell. Only use case I see is in a transition/migration phase when converting Java code to Kotlin or maybe some library code that doesn't want to expose nullable values.  All other cases should use nullable values. That's what they're for.

Comment: "Can not evaluate the expression: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Failed to generate expression: KtNameReferenceExpression"

Comment: Does it always work? I cannot see it on a `MediaPlayer` instance I created and stored as a `lateinit` `var`.

Comment: I come back to this answer so often ...

Comment: what if the lateinit property is inside an object not a class?

Answer (score 181):

Using `.isInitialized` property one can check initialization state of a lateinit variable.

```
if (::file.isInitialized) {
    // File is initialized
} else {
    // File is not initialized
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21646722)

Comment: @gforce301 It will definetly used for checking.

Comment: Well this is the only answer that worked for me on Android Studio having Kotlin version 1.3

Comment: @gforce301 why does this not answer the question??  Was the original question changed?  It seems to answer it now...

Answer (score 106):

You can easily do this by:

```
::variableName.isInitialized
```

or

```
this::variableName.isInitialized
```

But if you are inside a listener or inner class, do this:

```
this@OuterClassName::variableName.isInitialized
```

Note: The above statements work fine if you are writing them in the same file(same class or inner class) where the variable is declared but this will not work **if you want to check the variable of other class (which could be a superclass or any other class which is instantiated)**, for ex:

```
class Test {
    lateinit var str:String
}
```

And to check if str is initialized:

[image]

What we are doing here: checking `isInitialized` for field `str` of `Test` class in `Test2` class.
And we get an error backing field of var is not accessible at this point.
Check a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549015/isinitialized-backing-field-of-lateinit-var-is-not-accessible-at-this-point) already raised about this.

Answer (score 48):

Try to use it and you will receive a `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` if it is not initialized.

`lateinit` is specifically for cases where fields are initialized after construction, but before actual use (a model which most injection frameworks use).
If this is not your use case `lateinit` might not be the right choice.

EDIT: Based on what you want to do something like this would work better:

```
val chosenFile = SimpleObjectProperty<File?>
val button: Button

// Disables the button if chosenFile.get() is null
button.disableProperty.bind(chosenFile.isNull())
```

Comment: I have a JavaFX application, and I have a button which will be always disables unless a variable (which is `lateinit`) has been initialized. In other words: I want the button to be disabled as long as the variable hasn't been initialized. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: @MathewHany How would it be getting initialized normally? You might want to look at property getter/setters and a SimpleBooleanProperty which you can bind to the disabled property of the button

Comment: To be more specific, I have a simple app that contains 4 buttons, the first button will open a DirectoryChooser dialog, and the other 3 will be disabled, when the user choose a directory then all the other buttons will be available to the user.

Comment: @MathewHany you can natively implement that using a SimpleObjectProperty to hold the chosen file, then using the `isNull` binding to disable the other buttons.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized xsveda answer is more up to date

Comment: @Serge True, although for this specific question `lateinit` was not really the correct solution anyway

Answer (score 31):

If you have a `lateinit` property in one class and need to check if it is initialized from another class

```
if(foo::file.isInitialized) // this wouldn't work
```

The workaround I have found is to create a function to check if the property is initialized and then you can call that function from any other class.

**Example:**

```
class Foo() {

    private lateinit var myFile: File

    fun isFileInitialised() = ::file.isInitialized
}

 // in another class
class Bar() {

    val foo = Foo()

    if(foo.isFileInitialised()) // this should work
}
```

Comment: Kind of ridiculous that you need to add a function just to check if something is initialized.

Answer (score 21):

#### Checking lateinit var

To check whether a `lateinit var` was initialized or not, simply use an `.isInitialized` boolean on the property reference `::` .

```
if (foo::bar.isInitialized) {
    println(foo.bar)
}
```

Kotlin Playground's code may look like this:

```
fun main() {        
    var declarative = Declarative()
    declarative.checkLateInit()
}

class Declarative {   
    lateinit var compose: String

    fun checkLateInit() {            
        println(this::compose.isInitialized)
        compose = "Jetpack Compose 1.4"
      
        if (this::compose.isInitialized) {
            println(this.compose)
        }
    }
}

// Result:

// false
// Jetpack Compose 1.4
```

This checking is only available for the properties that are accessible lexically, i.e. declared in the same type or in one of the outer types, or at top level in the same file.

Comment: what is meaning of `::` before `bar`?

Comment: @Malwinder Singh "creates a member reference or a class reference" - Kotlin Doc

Answer (score 21):

[Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46584412/1084174) gives me a compiler error in `Kotlin 1.3+`, I had to explicitly mention the `this` keyword before `::`. Below is the working code.

```
lateinit var file: File

if (this::file.isInitialized) {

    // file is not null
}
```

Comment: I am using a local init variable when I use this check that gives an error like unresolved reference

Answer (score 3):

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property clientKeypair has not been initialized
```

Bytecode says...blah blah..

```
public final static synthetic access$getClientKeypair$p(Lcom/takharsh/ecdh/MainActivity;)Ljava/security/KeyPair;

`L0
LINENUMBER 11 L0
ALOAD 0
GETFIELD com/takharsh/ecdh/MainActivity.clientKeypair : Ljava/security/KeyPair;
DUP
IFNONNULL L1
LDC "clientKeypair"
INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    L1
ARETURN
```

L2
LOCALVARIABLE $this Lcom/takharsh/ecdh/MainActivity; L0 L2 0
MAXSTACK = 2
MAXLOCALS = 1

Kotlin creates an extra local variable of same instance and check if it null or not, if null then throws 'throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException' else return the local object.
Above bytecode explained [here](https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/lateinit-kotlin/)
Solution
Since kotlin 1.2 it allows you to check weather lateinit var has been initialized or not using `.isInitialized`