# isInitialized - Backing field of lateinit var is not accessible at this point

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I'm trying to check if a `lateinit` property has been initialized.
In Kotlin 1.2 we now have the `isInitialized` method for that. It works when I do that in the class where the lateinit property is declared.
But when I try to call this from another class I get the following warning:

> Backing field of 'lateinit var foo: Bar' is not accessible at this point

My model class (let's say `Person`) is written in Java
Two other classes (let's say `Test1` and `Test2`) are written in Kotlin

Example:

```
class Test1 {
    lateinit var person: Person

    fun method() {
        if (::person.isInitialized) {
            // This works
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
class Test2 {
    lateinit var test1: Test1

    fun method() {
        if (test1::person.isInitialized) {
            // Error
        }
    }
}
```

Any chance to get this working?

My current workaround is to make a method in Test1 which returns `isInitialized` from the `person` property.

```
fun isPersonInitialized(): Boolean = ::person.isInitialized

//in Test2:
if (test1.isPersonInitialized()) {
    // Works
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer. But why you use `isInitialized` over nullable? `lateinit` show always be initialized before the object being use.

Comment: @Eledgy your code does not compile. you cannot put an if-expression directly in a class body. i think you forgot to wrap it inside an init block. i know, this does not fix your inital problem.

Comment: @Joshua I have one case where person may not be initialized yet

Comment: @WilliMentzel It's just an example, I've put the code in a method

Comment: @ElegyD Then, you should use `Person?`. If you abuse `lateinit`, you need an if everytime you access person which make you go back to Java with null checking.

Comment: I had the same issue using a `protected lateinit var` in a superclass and then calling isInitialized from a subclass. It seems like the underlying Java implementation is just wrapping the variable with `if(variable != null) {}` so this seems strange.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized-since-12):

> This check is only available for the properties that are lexically accessible, i.e. declared in the same type or in one of the outer types, or at top level in the same file.

Which is why you cannot check that in the main function.

Comment: this should still be considered at kotlin v1.3.+ :)

Answer (score 108):

A really simple workaround to the constraints described by the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710377/2740621) is the following:

```
class LateClass {
    lateinit var thing: Thing
    fun isThingInitialized() = ::thing.isInitialized
}

class Client {
    val lateClass = LateClass()
    ... things happen ...
    if (lateClass.isThingInitialized() {
        // do stuff with lateClass.thing, safely
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice and elegant. converted to property.. val isThingInitialized: Boolean = ::thing.isInitialized

Comment: @TejasviHegde won't isThingInitialized be set to false on creation and never be updated to true once thing is initialized given that it is immutable?

Comment: @ThomasSunderland `isThingInitialized` is not immutable, it's a function.

Comment: @AutonomousApps I was speaking about Tejasvi's comment where they suggest that it can be a property and in their sample it is immutable

Comment: Is that preferred over var thing:Thing? = null? Why not instantiate to null?

Comment: `val isThingInitialized: Boolean = ::thing.isInitialized` will always be false since is pre-calculated only once. You can make a function as in this solution, or make a lazy field: `val isThingInitialized: Boolean by lazy { ::thing.isInitialized }`

Comment: what if you don't have access to the super class?

Comment: @TejasviHegde using a property can only be successful if you set up a getter to it.

Comment: thanks for that work around --> I liked it.

Answer (score 19):

My version as a Kotlin property.

```kotlin
class LateClass {
    lateinit var thing: Thing
    val isThingInitialized get() = this::thing.isInitialized 
}
```