# How to access variable.isInitialized from `apply` in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Let you have some variable and `apply`, `run`, `let`, `also`, `takeIf` or `with` function:

```
// private lateinit var someAdapter: SomeAdapter

recycler_view.apply {
    this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    if (this::someAdapter.isInitialized) { // Compilation error.
        this.adapter = someAdapter
    }
}
```

How to access a value or state of `someAdapter`?

Comment: Can you just reference `someAdapter` without prefixing it with `this`?

Comment: @MFazio23, yes, but `isInitialized` is unresolved.

Comment: Can you show the outer class code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the following.

```
recycler_view.apply {
    this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    if (this@OuterClass::someAdapter.isInitialized) { //qualified
        this.adapter = someAdapter
    }
}
```

Or

```
recycler_view.apply {
    this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    if (::someAdapter.isInitialized) { // qualified works for immediate outer scope
        this.adapter = someAdapter
    }
}
```

Comment: I must have been blind... I didn't see that `::someAdapter.isInitialized` on the page yet... until now :-) however I don't think that your comment there is valid... if `someAdapter` would be in any of the outer classes, it will still be accessible as long as there doesn't exist any other member that has the same name. And then it might just catch the wrong ;-)

Comment: Yes @Roland, I agree. What i meant was that it will resolve to the variable it finds in the immediate outer scope. But I see your point that it can actually cause confusion

Answer (score 3):

You can access it via `this@YourClass.adapter`. It's called qualified this, you can have a look at the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified)

Comment: Thanks, but now I can't get a state: `this@SomeFragment.someAdapter.isInitialized` (`isInitialized` is unresolved).

Comment: I don't know how `SomeAdapter` looks like, but that error says that `isInitialized` is not there, or is private.

Comment: It is an inline function, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618738/how-to-check-if-a-lateinit-variable-has-been-initialized. It checks whether `lateinit var` variable has already been initialized.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me in another case, when I accessed a view from nested `run`.

Answer (score 2):

Not direct answer, but rather design opinion: `lateinit var`s are supposed to be used when you're guaranteed to have them set before use.

`isInitialized` was not even present before Kotlin 1.2, it was only added (opinion ahead) as an error fallback.

If you're getting `notInitializedException` thats good indicator you're not properly initializing the field, if you explicitly initialize it later  then you should use nullable field instead: `SomeAdapter?`.

Comment: Agree with you, that's why I sometimes prefer `lateinit var`: it shows, when an application has a problem of events sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the outer `this` is possible via `this@OuterClass`. But, if you do not have any other `someAdapter` you can also just omit the `this@YourOuterClass` and simply use the following instead:

```
if (::someAdapter.isInitialized) {
```

So given the following, it is clear that `someVar` of `Outer` is meant:

```
class Outer<T> where T : Any {
  lateinit var someVar : T
  inner class Inner {
    fun isItInitialized() = ::someVar.isInitialized
  }
}
```

Given the following however:

```
class Outer<T> where T : Any {
  lateinit var someVar : T
  inner class Inner {
    lateinit var someVar : T
    fun isItInitialized() = ::someVar.isInitialized // now someVar of Inner is used
  }
}
```

you need to specify `this@Outer::someVar.isInitialized` if you want to access the outer `someVar`.