# Synchronize Firebase Database Query with another task

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

In my activity I have this **if** that has the value of the reference to query the DB

```
reference  = if (valor == 1){
            ConversationsAdapter.teste.child("messages")
        }else{
            MainActivity.usersChatReference.child("messages")
        }
```

The problem is, when I use that `reference` variable as reference to query my DB, I get an error saying "lateinit property reference has not been initialized". How can I make sure that the code above runs **before** this query code:

```
reference.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

            override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
                teste()
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick search it seems you can (and need to) safeguard your code against possibly not initializing the variable with:

```
if (::reference.isInitialized) {
  reference.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener{
  ...
```

Also see:

- [How to check if a "lateinit" variable has been initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618738/how-to-check-if-a-lateinit-variable-has-been-initialized)