# How to test if lateinit var is initialized from outside the class? - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618738/how-to-check-if-a-lateinit-variable-has-been-initialized) outlines how to test if a lateinit var has been initialized. However, in the example, the lateinit var is conveniently located within the same class.

How do you do the same thing from *outside* the class? This is the situation I have:

**Foo.kt**

```
class Foo {
    lateinit var foo: String
}
```

**Bar.kt**

```
class Bar {
    fun doSomething() {
        val foo = Foo().foo
        if (::foo.isInitialized) { // Unsupported [reference to variables aren't supported yet]
            Log.i("TAG", "do something")
        }
    }
}
```

What's the workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this was going to work, you'd need to do

```
val foo = Foo()
if (foo::foo.isInitialized)
    //...
```

The way you're doing it, you're trying to get a property reference of your local variable, which isn't a property. That's why the error says "reference to variables aren't supported yet" rather than "backing field not accessible at this point". Also, you'd be accessing the getter of the `lateinit` property when assigning the local variable, so it would fail if it weren't initialized yet.

But it doesn't work because of compiler limitations. You could simply add a getter

```
val fooReady: Boolean get() = ::foo.isInitialized
```

But I would say the design has very poor encapsulation if outside classes need to check whether a particular public property is initialized yet. In my opinion, any use of `isInitialized` is a code smell to begin with. If you need to guard calls to the getter with `isInitialized`, you might as well make the property nullable instead. Then you can use the familiar idioms of null checks instead of resorting to reflection, and it will work in a familiar way even for external classes that access it.

Comment: the idea here was that I wanted to use lateinit because the variable would never be null (except for when it hasn't yet been initialized) I am aware that I could simply make the variable nullable, but that would suggest "null" would be legitimate state of the variable, which is not.

Answer (score 0):

If object of another class has to make a decision based on whether or not the property is initialised, then having this property initialised - or answering whether or not it has already been initialised - is a public business capacity of your object and therefore I would recommend you to simply make it a part of your public API via `public fun isFooInitialised(): Boolean` function that utilises the fact that the object itself can inspect the state of its `lateinit` properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
latinit var foo


if (this::foo.isInitialized)
```