# How to retrieve all field of the current auth user in firestore? - Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How do I retrieve all the fields of the current user logged?

[image]

I've watched many tutorials and questions, and some of them talk about the whole collection, others about similar topics, but found no info about this.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Current Code:

```
  fun getUserName_FireBase(){
        if(userID==null){

            println("The userID is null")
            userID= getUserID()

            println("The userId has been assigned and now is: " + userID.toString())

        }

        println("1")

            val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        println("1a")
        val usersRef = db.collection("users")
        println("1b")

        usersRef.document(userID.toString()).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
               println("2")
               if (task.isSuccessful) {
                   println("3")
                   val document = task.result
                   if(document!!.exists()){
                       println("4")
                       userName = document!!.getString("user").toString()
                        println("user is " + userName.toString())
                   }else {
                       println("5")
                       Log.d("Error", "This document does not exist")

                   }

               }else {
                   println("6")
                   task.exception?.message?.let {
                       Log.d(TAG, it)
                   }

               }
               println("7")

           }
        println("8")
    }
```

Console error

The error is given because later I need to acces to userName var that is supposed to be filled in that function

[image]

Comment: Hmm. The answer it right in the getting started guide [Read Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document). Have you gone through that? If not, the Getting Started Guide really is the best place to Get Started.

Comment: @Jay Reading the guide, did not help sorry, I've just put this code                 var result=  FbReference.collection("users").document("$userID").get() and nothing happend, when put this other line to retrieve the field of username, println("result is " +result.getResult()!!.getString("user")), it says that Task is not complete yet

Comment: `DocumentReference.get()` returns a task object. You need to add a completion listener to get notified when the data has been fetched from the firestore.

Comment: See this line `println("8")` it will actually execute *before* the code within the Firebase closure, like this `userName = document!!` which means userName is undefined outside the closure. Code is faster than the internet and firebase data is only valid within the closure. [Firebase functions are asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774) so you should read up on that as it's the core issue in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to get user data, you have to create a reference that points to that document, perform a get() call and attach a listener, as seen in the following lines of code:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = db.collection("users")
usersRef.document("gA4z1AhkQpQ6J47sIMmCGIZRKDK2").get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val document = task.result
        if (document.exists()) {
            val email = document.getString("email")
            val pass = document.getString("pass")
            val user = document.getString("user")
            Log.d(TAG,"$email/$pass/$user")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "The document doesn't exist.")
        }
    } else {
        task.exception?.message?.let {
            Log.d(TAG, it)   
        }
    }
}
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
barrooroor@gmail.com/paport/do3fe4232ef2
```

If "gA4z1AhkQpQ6J47sIMmCGIZRKDK2" is the ID of the user that comes from the authentication process, then instead of the hard coded ID, you can simply use:

```
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid
usersRef.document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener {/* ... /*}
//
```

Besides that, something more important, **never** store sensitive data as passwords in plain text. Malicious users might take advantage of that. Always use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) for that and secure the database using [Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: Thank you Alex for the advice! I 've followed your instructions but the execution code completely ignores it, like as if it wasn't there. I added the current code with the console error, in case if I may missing something

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618738/how-to-check-if-a-lateinit-variable-has-been-initialized) will help, right?

Comment: No, Alex that specfied answer does not, but jay commented a question that you have answer some time ago, that may think that it could be the problem. So, big Thanks!!

Comment: @AlexMamo document() requires a String datatype but you supplied a String? datatype, was there no error at your end?

Comment: @oriohac Yes, document() requires a String datatype and I supplied a String. `"gA4z1AhkQpQ6J47sIMmCGIZRKDK2"` is a String.

Comment: what I mean is you supplied a String?. type, which is a string with null safety, here `val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid
usersRef.document(uid).get().addOnCompleteListener {/* ... /*}` so how could that work?

Comment: @oriohac Check [safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) in Kotlin.

Comment: I know about safe calls, why I'm asking because it flagged an error when I tried that out, until I used `auth.currentUser!!.uid`  which is a non-null asserted call.